# Help needed with partial products

Tags: self-learning

I understand that 4 times 6 tens is 240. I am now being asked to add the extra tens to 240. how do I do that? are the extra tens 40. so if I add 240+40=280 is that the answer?

Comment: Yes, you have $4\cdot 60+40=240+40=280$

Comment: You can also calculate $4\cdot 6\cdot 10+4\cdot 10=(4\cdot 6+4)\cdot 10=28\cdot 10=280$